# Procedure fires without being called

Tags: delphi, procedure, execution

Is it possible, in delphi, that a procedure fires without being called?

I have two completly different procedure. First one is a click on popup menu. The second one is a function which i defined to split a string.

And i don't call my split method in my click of popup menu but it fires anyway and i can't find why. Debugger just says he can't read adress 00000001 but i don't even want him to read cause i don't call this procedure in any of my popup options. Does anyone have any idea of why it could fire by its own?

I can edit code if you want but idk it will be usefull as both procedure arent linked x)

## CODE

```
procedure TBDDTool.pmDeleteColumnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  sListColNames : string;
begin
  fileModified := true;
  sListColNames := '';
  //Increment undo number
  Inc(undoNum);
  if undoNum = 11 then
    begin
      for i := 0 to Length(UndoArray) - 1 do
        begin
          if i < Length(UndoArray)-1 then
            UndoArray[i] := UndoArray[i+1];
        end;
    undoNum := UndoNum -1;
    end;
  //Add action to the array of undo actions
  undoArray[undoNum] := 'Deleted column:' + IntToStr(sgFilePreview.Col)
                       +'$'+aSourceData[0,sgFilePreview.Col] + '#deleted';
  pmUndo.Enabled := true;
  if (Pos('#primarykeypk', aSourceData[0, sgFilePreview.Col]) <> 0) then
    begin
      aSourceData[0,sgFilePreview.Col] := COPY(aSourceData[0,sgFilePreview.Col], 0, Pos('#primarykey', aSourceData[0, sgFilePreview.Col])-1);
      pmPrimaryKey.Enabled := true;
    end;

  if (Pos('#', aSourceData[0, sgFilePreview.Col]) <> 0) then
    aSourceData[0,sgFilePreview.Col] := COPY(aSourceData[0,sgFilePreview.Col], 0, Pos('#', aSourceData[0, sgFilePreview.Col])-1);

  for i := 0 to Length(aSourceData[0])-1 do
    begin
      if aSourceData[0,i] = sgFilePreview.Cells[sgFilePreview.Col, 0] then
      begin
        aSourceData[0,i] := aSourceData[0,i] + '#deleted';
        Break;
      end;
    end;

  //just set col width to 0 to hide it but we need the index
  sgFilePreview.ColWidths[sgFilePreview.Col] := 0;

end;

//Custom split method
function TBDDTool.Explode(const Separator, s: String;
  Limit: Integer): TStringDynArray;
var
  SepLen: Integer;
  F, P: PChar;
  ALen, Index: Integer;

begin

  SetLength(Result,0);
  //if the word passed is empty there's no need to continue
  if (S = '') or (Limit < 0) then Exit;
  if Separator = '' then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, 1);
    Result[0] := S;
    Exit;
  end;

  //Set to the length of the separator
  SepLen := Length(Separator);
  ALen := Limit;
  SetLength(Result, ALen);

  Index := 0;
  P := PChar(s);
  While P^ <> #0 do
  begin
    F := P;
    P := AnsiStrPos(P,PChar(Separator));
    if (P = nil) OR ((Limit > 0) AND (Index = Limit -1)) then  P := StrEnd(F);
    if Index >= ALen then
    begin
      Inc(ALen,5);
      SetLength(Result, ALen);
    end;
    SetString(Result[Index], F, P-F);
    INC(Index);
    if p^ <> #0 then Inc(P,SepLen);
  end;
  if index < ALen then SetLength(Result, Index);
  
end;
```

The explode functions is called when i click delet option (from a popup menu). But i don't call the explode function in my delete procedure. The break happens on `while P^ <> #0` line

Comment: It's not possible. And it's not possible for use to help you without code ....

Comment: There, i posted the code which create the bugs. Note that the delete option works fine in alsmot everycases. But sometimes it fires the Explode function without apparent reasons cause i don't even call it in my deleteClick option

Comment: the bug happend on P^ <> #0

Comment: @bummi any idea why this happens? :(

Comment: I've used break points to check if the delete function is completed and it goes to the final `end;` statement of the delete procedure. The explode functions is called after the delete procedure is completed :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible, in delphi, that a procedure fires without being called?

Generally speak, it is not possible. If code executes, something in the system made it execute.

However, it is possible that you have somehow corrupted memory. That in turn may lead to you calling one function and the corruption leading to a different function being called.

In order to debug this I suggest that you first of all inspect the call stack when the unexpected function begins executing. That should tell you how the execution reached that point. If that's not enough to explain things, cut your code down to the bare minimum that produces the problem. It's harder to find problems when there's lots of code. By cutting down to a minimum, you'll make it easier to see what has gone wrong.

Comment: It says `kernel32.RaiseExcepetion +0x52` folowwing the internet it means that an assembly is missing? And i know i have an error openning delphi, it says it can't load something . Could it be it? My application was waorking fine til now and the delete method works fine in overall. It just fires this `explode` function when i delete a certain column :/

Comment: It sayes it can't load a IDE package when opening delphi. Does this have something in common with the `kernel32.RaisException` exception?

Comment: `kernel32.RaiseExcepetion` does not mean that an assembly is missing. That's just the system function used to raise an exception. Entirely to be expected since you are encountering an exception. What you should do is what I describe in my answer.

Comment: In call stack it calls Explode with `(';',???,0)` just after `drawCell` event. i guess ??? causes the problem?

Comment: Not necessarily. We cannot see your `OnDrawCell` event handler. When you double click on that entry in the call stack it should take you to the source of the call. Anyway, there's no more that I can offer give the information in the question.

Comment: Oh wait, i just got it. The explode function is called in the draw cell so i can debug now. Hah, you're awesome thank you \o/ the delete function hides a column on the grid so it fires the ondrawcell in which i make the call to explode